# Wiring up 5+ meters of LED strips powered through USB

Tags: usb, esp8266

I am trying to power on about 5 meters of LED strips together with my ESP8266. The LEDs are called WS2812 and each LED is addressable.

After about 3.5-4 meters, the LEDs' colors starts to fade out (they start as white but end as yellow/orange). There are about 130-150 LEDs total and the voltage ranges from **2.8V** (at the top where they are white) to **2.5V** (at the bottom where they are orange).

The current I read out when all LEDs are powered on is about **1.08-1.1A** at **5.1V**, which means a total of **~5.6 watt**. That is a lot for a regular USB port, but it doesn't matter if I plug it into an USB 2.0 or 3.0 port (the cable is only 2.0).

I'm looking for a better way to power this, so there's no voltage drop near the end, so my thought was to use two USB cables instead. One acting as power and data, while the other is simply used for power (need to split them up).

I would have to hook it up in parallel, right? Is that just a matter of slicing up the USB cables, then join the two wires for power?

Is there a better way to do this? Grabbing an USB 3.0 cable might be able to solve this, but I really have no clue about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the power at both ends. Or in the middle.

[image]

The parallel connection of a larger gauge wire will reduce the voltage droop from the FPC significantly.

**Your problem though, seems to be that you are greatly overloading your power supply. 130 WS2812 rgb leds at full white take 60mA each meaning you are trying to pull 7.8 Amps through a 1 or 2 amp power supply. The voltage droop you are seeing is from overloading the power supply AND the resistance of the FPC.**

Comment: It's not possible to do this, if I want to power it from one end?

Comment: FPC has a high resistance per foot compared to regular 22 AWG wire likely in your usb cable. The led strip is acting as a resistor. There is no way to fix that without adding power to multiple points.

Comment: I have the LED strip wired around a cylinder. If I hook up two USB ports in parallel for power and then take two small wires from the beginning to the end, to make the resistance smaller, wouldn't that work?

Comment: Connecting two power supplies in parallel isn't recommended. Use a single 1+ Amp USB supply. 2.1 Amp usb supplies are cheap. But you already know what to do. Simply run the **two small wires from the beginning to the end.** 22 AWG would work fine. You are putting this wire in parallel with the FPC and reducing the resistance and voltage drop. ***Thats the same exact thing as providing power at both ends.***

Comment: Yeah, that's just weird, because when I hook up a regular cellphone charger (tried many from 1000-2000 mAh) and then wires from the beginning to the end, they do slightly change color, but they only get brighter. Hmm.

Comment: @MortenMoulder if you are getting 2.7 or 2.1 volts at one end, something else is wrong. If you are only drawing 1 Amp, a good 5V supply should be fairly close to 5V. Injecting power at multiple points is how this is done.

Comment: @MortenMoulder 130 leds, white at full brightness meaning 20mA * 3 diodes per led, = 7.8 AMPS. You see 2.x volts because you are greatly overloading your power supply.

Comment: Okay, I've taken my Samsung charger and it now works fine. It's not great, but it's definitely a big help. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Overloading such a power supply will often make it fail prematurely, FYI. You'd be better off with a suitably rated PSU.

Answer (score 0):

According to USB3.0 Standards to reach out to 5.3 meters of distance, your power cable can be allowed to have 3.58 Ohms per 100 meter. Most cables on the market are not exactly up to the mark. To keep the LED brightness at the same level, you need to check how much voltage drop you are getting at the end- should be less than 5%. If it is greater than that, go for slicing the USB plugs and solder thicker power cables in parallel.